# How to change an existing normal axis to cartopy axis in different size subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I made a figure of three subplots with different size, but I don't know how to change the left one to lat-lon projection provided by cartopy. I want only the left subplot to have the property of `projection : ccrs.PlateCarree()` or `transform = ccrs.PlateCarree()` so that I can plot a map on it, while the other two subplots on the right should remain unchanged. Can someone tell me where I should put the projection information?
Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic("AABB;AABB;AACC", figsize = (16, 6))
plt.show()
```

[image]

All comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the higher level methods like `subplots` or `subplot_mosaic`. But when you use the `GridSpec` method, you can provide axes-specific keywords.

For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3), constrained_layout=True, facecolor="w")
gs = GridSpec(3, 3, figure=fig)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:3, 1])

ax1.set_extent((-90,90,90,-90))
ax1.coastlines()
ax2.imshow(np.random.rand(10,17))
ax3.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum())
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html

[image]